# Gradle: Renaming playBinary distribution scripts

Tags: gradle, playframework

I simply want to rename `./bin/playBinary` generated by gradle dist with the "play" plugin to `./bin/foobar` to ease transition from SBT.

I thought something like this or some variant would work, but haven't been able to solve it. I know the [Gradle Distribution Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) is being used here under the covers.

```
model {
  distributions {
    playBinary {
      contents {
        from('bin') {
          rename '.*playBinary', 'foobar'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate your advice